# Why did the Thalmor decide that the Talos worship should be banned

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, the-elder-scrolls-series

When I learned about the Civil War in Skyrim, I learned, that the imperials and Stormcloaks are in war, I also found out about the Thalmor, who started the great War in Cyrodiil and forced the Empire to sign a peace treaty about banning the worship of Talos since the Empire lost. Why did the Thalmor suggest that the worship of Talos should be banned?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [TES Wiki, "Thalmor (Skyrim)" article](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Thalmor_(Skyrim)):

> As a branch of the Aldmeri Dominion, the Thalmor seeks to unify the
>   Provinces of Tamriel through one-government leadership, with Elves
>   holding all places of power. The reasons behind the ban on the worship
>   of Talos are shrouded in doubt, however, the two most probable
>   hypotheses are either that there simply is animosity towards what
>   Talos represents (human turned god and the victories of Tiber Septim)
>   or that it may just be intended to cause distress in provinces like
>   Skyrim and thus weaken the Empire. Deeply offended by Tiber Septim's
>   victory in Valenwood, members of the Thalmor have sworn to root out
>   Talos worship in the Empire.

Also, found a good [post on Reddit - /r/teslore "Why did the Thalmor ban the worship of Talos?"](https://www.reddit.com/r/teslore/comments/3b953w/why_did_the_thalmor_ban_the_worship_of_talos/) by user, ginja_ninja describing it. You can read the full discussion, but this the most in depth explanation I could find (paraphrased somewhat):

> The Thalmor, and arguably all Altmer, hate Talos first and foremost
>   because of Tiber Septim and what he did to their homeland. In the
>   dying light of the Second Era, the newly formed Third Empire had
>   reached a tenuous peace with the Aldmeri Dominion because Septim and
>   Arctus knew they didn't have the manpower or tech to conquer the Isles
>   in the way they'd taken Hammerfell. Though he'd been prophecied to be
>   the first to rule all of Tamriel, Septim was originally content to
>   resign himself to owning the provinces of men and coexisting with the
>   Altmer.
>
> Then Vivec gave him access to the Numidium. And everything changed.
>
> With the power of Walk-Brass and the souls of Wulfharth-Arctus mingled
>   with his own fueling it, nothing could stand against the might of
>   Septim anon Talos Stormcrown, a fabrication made into reality and
>   registered unto the firmament by a stolen god. Not even the oldest and
>   mightiest civilization on the planet, previously so content and secure
>   in their objective superiority, could do anything but despair as it
>   crossed their threshold and imposed ultimate destruction, demanded
>   absolute capitulation.
>
> And so in less than a day the ancient, proud, and noble denizens of
>   Alinor were forced to bow before their conqueror, a human, with the
>   only alternative being rendered into a roiling time-wound in the sea.
>
> Over the next century, they were forced to watch this man they could
>   only consider a war criminal venerated and sanctified all the way to
>   the status of a god, elevated to the station of Lord of the Divines as
>   a reward for his thievery and warping of the cosmic order. They
>   watched generations of men live, die, and forget as the story became
>   more and more twisted and the atrocities remembered less and less
>   until this conqueror was the greatest hero of all mankind, absolved of
>   any wrongdoing by the ignorance afforded by generational legacy and
>   selective memory endemic to the very nature of man.
>
> Now remember how long Altmer live for. It's been a little over six
>   hundred years since the beginning of the Third Era. There are plenty
>   of Altmer alive in 4E201 who were around to experience Tiber Septim's
>   conquest firsthand. He isn't some ancient figure of legend to them.
>   Hell, he's younger than a good number of them. Are you beginning to
>   grasp how infuriating it must be to watch generations of humans live
>   and die and spawn and pass on selective knowledge to their spawn that
>   conveniently leaves out everything bad Talos did to achieve the
>   greater good? To watch a bunch of foolish, barely-literate Nords beat
>   their chests in vehement defense of a megalomaniac they only remember
>   from the romanticized stories of their almost-certainly-illiterate
>   grandfather's grandfather's great-grandfather?
>
> The metaphysical justifications come second, and are a compound
>   effect, abstracted by Aldmeri philosophers and theologians to further
>   strengthen the oppositional rhetoric. First and foremost though, they
>   want revenge. They want to right the effects caused from when they
>   were wronged. They want to stop the momentum of those effects
>   reverberating forward through a genealogy. But it becomes a complex
>   issue since the enemy they're fighting is a progenic proxy. Their true
>   enemies are all dead of old age. They're fighting a legacy. The only
>   enemies they have now are arguably innocent, unable to truly
>   understand due to their short lifespans.